# Generic Lookup table using fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I can't figure out how to map a table structure like below within fluent nhibernate.  Based on how I have the data laid about below you can see that there is no direct relationship between the Transaction or Member table and the CodeSet table.  The id goes directly to the CodeValue table.  So inside code you will find hardcoded values for the CodeSet tables.  This is old code and I don't know if I should just change it or if nHibernate can deal with it.

I have the following tables:

Generic Lookup tables:

**CodeSet**

```
    ID
    Name
    Display
```

**CodeValue**

```
    ID
    CodeSetId
    Name
    Display
    ReferenceValue
```

I then have tables like

**Transaction**

```
    ID
    TransactionTypeId
    Name
```

**Member**

```
    ID
    FirstName
    LastName
    MemberTypeId
```

The **TransactionTypeId** and **MemberTypeId** relates back to the CodeValueId on the CodeValue table.

### So the data would look like:

#### CodeSetId      Name                 Display

- 1                 "TransactionType"    "Transaction Type"
- 2                 "MemberType"         "Member Type"

#### CodeValueId    CodeSetId   Name         Display     ReferenceValue

- 1              1           ER Visit     ER Visit    100
- 2              1           Surgery      Surgery     200
- 3              2           Doctor       Doctor      500
- 4              2           Patient      Patient     600

#### TransactionId    TransactionTypeId   Name

- 1                 1                   Some ER Transaction
- 2                 2                   Some Surgery Transaction

#### MemberId         FirstName          LastName        MemberTypeId

- 1                 Betty              Boo (Doctor)    3
- 2                 Sammy              Sue (Patient)   4

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read or walkthrough the 'Your first project' in the Fluent NHibernate 'Getting Started' document.

The retail company example has a very similar structure to what you're trying to implement.

https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started